# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea

```
private final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/adventure.db";
```

This always returns:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
> found for jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/adventure.db

I've heard there was a possible way to fix this by going to View > Tool Windows > Database, hitting the + button, and then when creating the new SQLite database, click on the Driver: SQLite link to be able to download the SQLite driver. However, I've done that many times. It has failed every time because I receive the exact same error.

There's also a solution I read where you can supposedly type in:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

That doesn't work either. I just get hit with the error

> "Cannot resolve symbol 'forName'"

So I'm just at a dead end because none of the solutions work for me. How am I supposed to fix this error that has been a pain in the ass?

Comment: You need to make sure the SQLite jdbc driver is added in your application classpath. If you use Gradle or Maven - add it in build.gradle or pom.xml files as dependencies. If you are managing build and dependencies without Maven or Gradle - [add them in IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency).

Comment: did you found a solution? inside the intelJ Database GUI its no problem. i could create or edit Tables